# Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with -6)

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorboard

I am trying to load and open  Tensorboard using jupyter notebook. my code is run and the model is training without a problem, but when I started to load the Tensorboard I got this error?

ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with -6).
Contents of stderr:
[libprotobuf ERROR external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:393] Invalid file descriptor data passed to EncodedDescriptorDatabase::Add().
[libprotobuf FATAL external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1367] CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException: CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size):

I have the same env for both Tf-2 and Tensorboard.
Any one can help pls?
Thanks.

Comment: What commands are you using to launch tensorboard from google colab?

Comment: I have used  " %tensorboard --logdir logs " in jupyter notbook.